# How to respond to container's click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have a list item with 2 links in it:

```
<li>
   <a href="foo.htm">Foo</a>
   <a href="bar.htm">Bar</a>
</li>
```

If a user clicks on "Foo", I want to send the user to foo.htm. If the user clicks on any part of the `<li>` or on "Bar", I want to send the user to bar.htm. I'm worried if I attach a click event listener to the `<li>` that clicks to "Foo" will send the user to bar.htm.

Comment: Seems fine http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4nPmd/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried using event.stopPropagation()

```
$("a[href='foo.html']").click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation()
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this. stopPropagation shouldn't be needed, as I understand you want links to take to the specified locations anyway.

```
$("li").click(function(e){
    //just in case the click on li is processed before link click
    if($("a[href='foo.html']").is(e.target)){
        window.location.href = "foo.html";
    }
    else {
        window.location.href = "bar.html";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code should solve your problem.

```
$("li").click(function (e) {
            if(e.target.nodeName == "A" && e.target.href.indexOf("foo.html") !== -1){
                //send foo.html
            }
            event.stopPropagation();
            // send bar.html
           return false.
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `event.stopPropagation()` on the handlers of both Foo and Bar, see a working solution [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/8cduk/3/)

**Pasting the jsfiddle code here for convenience**:

HTML:

```
<li id="l1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <a href="http://www.google.es/q=foo" id="foo">Foo</a>
   <a href="http://www.google.es/q=bar" id="bar">Bar</a>
</li>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$('#foo').bind('click',function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
$('#bar').bind('click',function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
$('#l1').bind('click',function() {
    window.location.href = $('#bar').attr('href');
});​
```